# Blender opens user preferences when starting

Tags: customization

I don't know what I've done but all the sudden whenever I open blender, it starts with the preference window open too, looking like this

[image]

Even resetting blender to factory defaults doesn't change it. Why is this happening and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Could be that you've saved the startup file while having the user preferences open.

Comment: Yup. Close the preference window, and File > Defaults > 'Save Startup File'

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't do like Robert and Robin suggested (you edited the startup file while it was open) maybe check your permissions. You will need read/write permissions in your config preferences files. That's the 'rw' below.

In Linux:

```
ls -la ~/.config/blender/3.0/config/ total 168 drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom   4096 Jan 15 00:43 . drwxr-xr-x 3 tom tom   4096 Dec 15 12:57 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom     69 Jan 15 00:43 bookmarks.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom    382 Jan 15 00:43 platform_support.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom     42 Jan 15 00:43 recent-files.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 149264 Dec 15 12:57 userpref.blend
```

I guess you could fix it maybe with `chmod -Rv u+rw ~/.config/blender/3.0/config/` potentially.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly relate to permissions. If Blender had problems accessing its user preferences folder, it would open as if you pressed File -> Defaults -> "Load Factory Settings" and User Preferences window is not open by default then. It's possible to open User Preferences from a script with `bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show()`, but that would be one weird script. The only likely logical explanation is that startup file got saved this way. I gave this answer a downvote, because  to the best of my knowledge this cannot be correct.